# Don't Work Tooltip in Laravel Controller (JS)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tooltip

Don't work Public Function with JS Code and Tooltip in laravel!

```
public function recentActions()
    {
        $b = \Cache::remember('indexBans',10,function()
        {
            $(function () {$('.mt').tooltip({template: '<div class="tooltip md-tooltip-main"><div class="tooltip-arrow md-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner md-inner-main"></div></div>'});});
            $html = '';$actions = Ban::latest('BanTime')->where('Sil','=',0)->take(5)->get();
            if($actions->isEmpty()) $html .= '<div class="feed-element">No recent bans.</div>';
            foreach($actions as $row)
            {
                $user = @User::where('user',$row->Player)->first();
                $admin = @User::where('user',$row->Admin)->first();
                $html .= '<div class="feed-element"><img src="'.URL::to('/').'/assets/a/'.$user->Skin.'.png" class="pull-left img-circle mt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="TEST HTML" style="height:38px;"><div class="media-body ">'.(isset($row->user) ? $row->user->url : $row->Player).' was banned by '.$row->admin->url.'. Reason: '.$row->Reason.' <br><small class="text-muted green"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row->BanTime)->diffForHumans().' ('.$row->BanTime.')</small></div></div>';
            }
            return $html;
        });
        return $b;
    }
```

Errors:

> [2019-10-03 11:31:34] production.ERROR: exception
> 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
> 'syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$''
> in
> /home2/linkman2/public_html/panel/app/Http/Controllers/ActionController.php:42
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}

Comment: You forgot either ( or )  in the $html .=  maybe this ->  (isset

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues in your code :

- `...src="'.URL::to('/').'/assets...`
- and `...'.Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row->BanTime)->diffForHumans().'....`

you are using a string with single quote and you put a single quote in concatenation `to('/')` and here `('Y-m-d H:i:s'` so you have to change single quote with double quote.

```
$html .= '<div class="feed-element"><img src="'.URL::to("/").'/assets/a/'.$user->Skin.'.png" class="pull-left img-circle mt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="TEST HTML" style="height:38px;"><div class="media-body ">'.(isset($row->user) ? $row->user->url : $row->Player).' was banned by '.$row->admin->url.'. Reason: '.$row->Reason.' <br><small class="text-muted green"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$row->BanTime)->diffForHumans().' ('.$row->BanTime.')</small></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this function, not $html!!

```
$(function () {$('.mt').tooltip({template: '<div class="tooltip md-tooltip-main"><div class="tooltip-arrow md-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner md-inner-main"></div></div>'});});
```